# Shell script gives lots of these things ''' as output and it never did before

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cygwin, backup

Best to just tell you the input/output and you will see why it is weird. Should be a quick fix for someone good at this, I took a day just to write this script.

**Steps I took:**

Run AutoBackup.bat

```
C:\cygwin\bin\sh AutoBackupShell.sh
pause
```

AutoBackup.bat calls AutoBackupShell.sh

```
name=`C:/cygwin/bin/date +'backup_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'`
end="_Engine"
name=$name$end
C:/cygwin/bin/cp -r ./Engine Backups/$name
```

Output is a folder like this: **backup_2014_07_16_19_07_14_Engine**

Something to note is that on my windows machine those weird question mark boxes look
like these ''' kind of, just more centered vertically.

For reference the output should look like this: **backup_2014_07_16_19_07_14_Engine**

Computer notes:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Using cygwin for sh

*Another thing I need to do after I figure out why I get weird characters is how to only
copy files with specific extensions for backup. It's not part of the question but a little direction would help me out.*

Comment: I realize this is unsolicited advice, so take it with a grain of salt, but even so: dump Cygwin, it's a mess.  If you want to use UNIX, use a real UNIX, Linux or OpenBSD or whatever, in a virtual machine if that is appropriate.  If you want to use Windows, learn PowerShell or another Windows technology of your choice.  Trying to live in a half-and-half world, you're just going to get caught by lots of silly problems like this one.  (YMMV.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce, but I got the good result...

Your issue seams to be that your double-quotes was not substitutes during the setting of **end** variable. Could you check you are using simple double-quote (0022) and not an exotic quote like "00AB: left pointing double quotation mark".

Comment: So mcoolive u almost got it right. You led me in the right direction. I ended up searching the fire for '\r' line endings and removing them. They were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

make a separate variable name like and use it where ever you like. I think that will fix the issue of characters.

```
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-$file")
```

to copy use

```
cp $1 $2
```

hope this helps.

Comment: My computer doesn't like that answer. DATE=$(C:/cygwin/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") doesn't work. I don't think it likes the $ sign.